# Detect the update version of Microsoft Internet Explorer 11 using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

How can I detect the update version of IE11 (e.g. 11.0.80)? I only found snippets in the major version like this:

```
function GetIEVersion() {
  var sAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
  var Idx = sAgent.indexOf("MSIE");

  // If IE, return version number.
  if (Idx > 0) 
    return parseInt(sAgent.substring(Idx+ 5, sAgent.indexOf(".", Idx)));

  // If IE 11 then look for Updated user agent string.
  else if (!!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7\./)) 
    return 11;

  else
    return 0; //It is not IE
}

if (GetIEVersion() > 0) 
   alert("This is IE " + GetIEVersion());
else 
   alert("This is not IE.");
```

### Background

In our company, the software deployment is handled by a dedicated department. They seem to have a mess with different IE update versions, that cause issues on some web apps. Sadly, we can't directly influence those apartments and they don't really see the problem.

To get an overview which update versions are used by our employees (more thousands), I want track them using Matomo.

## Is it possible?

It doesn't seem possible, but maybe someone has an alternative idea. Our main problem is that some things break in some updated versions. I'd like to use something like feature detection, which seems better practice. Sadly, I can't find some overview documentation about the IE update versions that show me what is possible on which update state and what's not.

I know that the best solution would be updating EVERY machine to the latest update version and look why this currently doesn't happen. But as you may know, it's hard to realize this in the larger company's, where another department is responsible for them.

Comment: My update is 11.0.47 but its truncated in the useragent string: *Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko* so that level of granularity is not possible.

Comment: In an active directory domain you could create a script to perform a version lookup for each joined machine.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suspicion getting a concrete version on IE not possible by a user-agent. (only v.11.0) As @Alex K. told need to create some custom script track them somehow.
1) My idea is to make force update of all PCs to the latest version of the browser (maybe with security packages) and then you can rely on this updates. This is the best way as you mention as well :). 2) Another way - make a tiny app/windows service and install it for every PCs in your local network. The app will track browser version only and send info to your server. 3) One more thing - kind of stupid - ask users to check the version by them and send in some fancy dialog windows inside the corporate home page. 4) Try to find the special difference of your target IE version. If there are some js updates, you can make exception intentionally and track it.
I just imagine. If you have no rights to make any programmatical impact on your PCs I afraid it's impossible. imho.

p.s. use default Chrome for the corporate network. Chrome sends a concrete version via UA